# Avoid Sending Email when User Post New Listing

Tags: osclass

I am new to `OSClass`, right now when user publish a listing an email has been sent to user's email id, in which user can activate that listing, admin can also activate that listing.

But I want that only admin should have control to activate the listing, so if somehow I can control that if I skip that step of sending email to user's email account.

Is there any solution?

Regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the email sending removing the hooks.

Edit your oc-load.php file and add this lines:

```
osc_remove_hook('hook_email_new_item_non_register_user', 'fn_email_new_item_non_register_user');
osc_remove_hook('hook_email_item_validation_non_register_user', 'fn_email_item_validation_non_register_user');
osc_remove_hook('hook_email_item_validation', 'fn_email_item_validation');
```

If you doubts of hooks you can take a look at http://doc.osclass.org/Hooks

you can create a plugin for this and this way you don't modify the osclass core files, you can check how here http://doc.osclass.org/How_to_create_a_plugin